# Remove .html off URL. .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm building a site in a Node.js container, and the .htaccess is not working.  I just want to remove the .html off the url, but the following just downloads the pages as files.  Sorry if this has been answered, just need help.  Thanks!

What we currently have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove .html all you need to use is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

EDIT:

Some hosting services require a slightly different layout:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: That just downloads the file, any idea why?  Thanks

Comment: See edit, might help your issue. But both of those will remove .html from your URL.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Still doesn't work.  Currently the .htaccess file is in the site folder, and I've tried it in the public folder as well, but it doesn't work.  Does it need to be in a different folder?  Thanks again!

Comment: It needs to be in your root. As long as it is there it should work fine :/... have you got anything else in your `.htaccess` which might be conflicting with it?

Comment: No, nothing at all.  It's so odd.  I can't think as to why this isn't working.

Comment: What version of Apache are you running?